# "Function not defined" error

Tags: php, php-5.3

I have a class which is :

```
<?php
class FileObject{

        private $name;
        private $arr;

        function __construct($name){

            $this->name = $name;
        $arr = array();

        }


        public function readFile(){
        $fileHandler = fopen($this->name, "rb");

        while (!feof($fileHandler) ) {

$line_of_text = fgets($fileHandler);
$parts = explode(' ', $line_of_text);
$count = 0;
foreach($parts as $tokens){
$arr[$tokens] = $count;
$count++;
}
}

if(checkInArr("fox"))
echo "yes";
else
echo "no";

ksort($arr);
print_r($arr);
fclose($fileHandler);
        }

        function checkInArr($needle){

            if(array_key_exists($needle,$arr))
            return TRUE;
            else
            return FALSE;

        }

}

?>
```

and I'm getting this error:

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined function checkInArr() in
>   C:\wamp\www\jbglobal\file_lib.php on line 29`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
if($this->checkInArr("fox"))
{
    echo "yes";
}
else
{
    echo "no";
}
```

Creating the `checkInArr();` method is somewhat redundant though unless you plan to do some more advanced detection, you should just use `array_key_exists($needle, $arr)` in that `if` statement.

```
if(array_key_exists('fox', $this->arr))
{
    echo "yes";
}
else
{
    echo "no";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->checkInArr()
```

As this function is a class method.